# Cannot publish legacy Xamarin android app after updating VS 2022 to version 17.5

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

After updating Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition to version 17.5 I am unable to publish android app created with Xamarin. App is old and I am not exactly familiar with .NET/MS env and community (Python Web Dev). So please bear with me.

Up to version 17.5 there was no problem. After update when I try to "Archive" app process of app archivisation starts and... after couple seconds nothing happens.

There is no bug or error in console.

Issue occurs on VS2022 CE for Mac and also on Windows.

For a workaround I am using VS2019 CE for Mac, but there is another issue here.

Even if I clear project, change it from debug to release and from release to debug couple of time, delete all compiled apps from android emulator, from time to time VS archives version from couple days before. I am aware that there could be older version archivized so I delete them earlier.

Is there any solution for that? What information I should provide that may help solve the problem?

I was unable to find older versions of VS2022 CE for mac on MS websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual studio installer to roll back to the previous version.

Rolling back to a previous version of Visual Studio is pretty straightforward. Using the Visual Studio Installer, press the More button on the relevant product card and look for the ‘Rollback to previous version’ option. When you press that, you’ll see a pop-up warning you that you’re about to rollback Visual Studio, you can either proceed or cancel the process.

Comment: Hey I tested it on MacOS edition but didnt have acces to Windows machine for a while. 
Unfortunately on MacOS edition there is no such option. A moment ago I asked my colleague to verify it on Windows and she doesn't have that option either.
I think that option might be avaible on Professional or Enterprise version only.

Comment: Well, the microsoft only provide the new version for the Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. But you can try the [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/).